# bash script to log as another user and keep the terminal open

Tags: bash

I have set up a http server at localhost, with several sites. I would like to connect to each site root folder, at the same way I used to at a remote server via ssh. So, I tried to create a bash script, intended to log as user "http", giving the site root folder as argument and change the $HOME to the site root folder:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Connecting to $1 as http...";
read -p "Contraseña: " -s pass;
su - http << EOSU >/dev/null 2>&1
$pass
export HOME="/srv/http/$1";
echo $HOME;
source .bash_profile;
exec $SHELL;
EOFSU
```

It does not work, basically because of:

1. `echo $HOME` keeps giving out the home folder of the user launching the script.
2. when the script reaches the end, it ends (obvious), but I would like that it stays open, so I could have a terminal session for user "http" and go on typing commands.

In other words, I am looking for a script that saves me 3 commands:

```
# su - http
# cd <site_root_folder>
# export HOME=<site_root_folder>
```

**Edit:**

Someone suggested the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

init_commands=(
    "export HOME=/srv/http/$(printf '%q' "$1")"
    'cd $HOME'
    '. .bash_profile'
)

su http -- --init-file <(printf '%s\n' "${init_commands[@]}")
```

I am sorry but their post is gone... In any case, this give me out `bash: /dev/fd/63: permission denied`. I am not so skillful to understand the commands above and try to sort it out. Can someone help me?

Thanks.

**Possible solution:**

I have been playing around, based on what was posted and some googling, and finally I got it :-)

```
trap 'rm -f "$TMP"' EXIT
TMP=$(mktemp) || exit 1
chmod a+r $TMP
cat >$TMP <<EOF
    export HOME=/srv/http/$(printf '%q' "$1")
    cd \$HOME
    . .bash_profile
EOF
su http -- --init-file $TMP
```

I admit it is not a nice code, because of:

1. the temporary file is created by the user executing the script and later I have to `chmod a+r` so user "http" can access... not so good.
2. I am sure this can be done on the fly, without creating a tmp file.

If some can improve it, it will be welcome; although in any case, it works!

Comment: As an aside, the here-doc delimiter isn't the same at the beginning and end (`EOSU` vs. `EOFSU`)

Comment: Have you tried `echo \$HOME` ?

Comment: I just tried and it worked, then my export line should be `export \HOME="/srv/http/$1";` ? (echo line is used just for checking)

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that the *$HOME* is evaluated as when the user run the script, meaning that it will get his evaluation of *$HOME* instead of evaluating it as the given user.

You can evaluate the *$HOME* as the given user (using the [eval](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/eval.1p.html) command) but I wont recommend it, it is generally bad practice to use this kind of evaluation, especially when talking about security.

I can recommend you to get the specific user home directory with standard linux tools like *passwd*

Example of the behavior you are seeing:

```
# expected output is /home/eliott
$ sudo -u eliott echo $HOME
/root
```

Working it around with *passwd*:

```
$ sudo -u eliott echo $(getent passwd eliott | cut -d: -f6)
/home/eliott
```